# Javascript code does not work in WordPress Theme files

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am currently creating a WP theme and added some HTML, CSS and JS to have some text flying in. I found the code at another website and altered it a bit for my website. When I used this on a static index.html file (without a backend language), it worked perfectly fine for me. But once I copied over that same code to my WordPress files the JS doesn't seem to work anymore. However, I did a test with an alert window to see if I correctly linked my JS files and this worked. Just the code that should make the text animated does not work. Any ideas why that is? here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="content_video">
  <h2 class="ml3">Hello World</h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Content on Video Background Animnation */

.ml3 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

functions.php: (to add my js file and external file)

```
<?php

function lux_files() {
 wp_enqueue_script( "javascript2", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js", false );
 wp_enqueue_script( "javascript", get_template_directory_uri() . '/index.js', array(), false );
 wp_enqueue_style("font-awesome", "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
 wp_enqueue_style("google-fonts", "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Raleway:400,700&display=swap");
 wp_enqueue_style("main_styles", get_stylesheet_uri());
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lux_files');



function lux_features() {
  add_theme_support('title-tag');
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'lux_features');

?>
```

JS file

```
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml3');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime.timeline()
  .add({
    targets: '.ml3 .letter',
    opacity: [0,1],
    easing: "easeInOutQuad",
    duration: 2250,
    delay: (el, i) => 150 * (i+1)
  });
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your console when you inspect the page?

Comment: yes, sorry, completely forgot to add that as well. That's the error I am getting: uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'textContent' of null

Answer (score 1):

Load jQuery library then in your javascript file try these codes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

    var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml3');
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

    anime.timeline().add({
        targets: '.ml3 .letter',
        opacity: [0,1],
        easing: "easeInOutQuad",
        duration: 2250,
        delay: (el, i) => 150 * (i+1)
    });

});
```